# How to duplicate a post?

Tags: slack

[A post on Slack](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/203950418-Compose-a-post) is a great way to quickly create and share structured and formatted information. I use it mostly to document custom features of our Slack workspace for our users.

I am now looking into making a checklist for onboarding and I want to create a template and then duplicate that template each time I need to use the checklist.

However, there does not seem to be a way to duplicate an existing post. Does anybody know a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Slack support team answered my question and its indeed not possible to duplicate posts. However, they suggested a workaround.

Here is the reply from the Slack support team:

> There isn't a way to duplicate messages natively in Slack just yet,
>   but I am more than happy to pass your message along to the team so
>   they can consider adding this down the road!
>
> Currently, the way we work around this in Slack is to create templates
>   and pin them to channels. You can make sure the template Post isn't
>   modified by unticking the box to "Let others edit this Post" when
>   sharing the Post initially. Similarly, formatted messages can only be
>   modified by the creator of the message so you won't need to worry
>   about these being modified.